# Maximum Coin Changes That Does Not Add To a Dollar

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, dynamic-programming

What is the maximal amount of money attained from coins of 1, 5, 10, 25 cent denominations that none of its subset amounts to 100 cents? We can find the solution with exhaustive or naive dynamic programming but I am looking for a clever approach, say a clever dynamic programming algorithm.

What is the general algorithm for the following generalized version of this problem?

$(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ is an n-tuple of natural numbers and $s$ a natural number. Let $A=\big\{(a_i)_{i=1}^n\big|b_i\le a_i \implies\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix_i\ne s,\, b_i\in \overline{\mathbb Z^-}\big\}$. Find 
$$\max_{(a_i)_{i=1}^n\in A}\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$$
and all maximizing non-negative tuples $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$'s.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, where every coin value can be created from other coins with the exception of 25 cents not being created from 10 cent coins, the maximum amount is obviously 1x25 + 9x10 + 4x1. But if we replaced "100 cent" with "99 cent", there would be no limit as long as we don't use four 1 cent coins.

The target amount (here: 100 cent) must be a multiple of each coin value, otherwise we use an unlimited amount of that coin. So it must be a multiple of the LCM of all coin values, here: 50 cent. That also limits how many of each coin we can have; here: 3x25, 9x10, 19x5, 99x1 cent. You can further limit the numbers: If you had 5x1 cent, then changing it for 1x5 cent could only improve things because you would have fewer choices for subsets etc. So you have at most 3x25, 9x10, 1x5, 4x1 cent. We can assume 4 single cents because gcd (25, 10, 5) = 5. That very much reduces your choices.

Comment: Actually, we can apply your replacement strategy with a slight generalization, by replacing one denomination with not a single but combination of multiple higher denominations. In the case of (3x25, 9x10, 19x5, 99x1), replace 5x10 with 2x25, then 19x5 with 3x25+2x10, then 95x1 with 3x25+2x10. We have (3x25,4x10,4x1). Using all of the coins we get the maximum amount 119 cents. Maybe we can start thinking about whether this is an optimal algorithm for the general problem, by applying your generalized replacement strategy starting from the highest denomination then downward.

Comment: My derivation in my previous comment is not entirely correct. The reason is the replacement strategy needs a constraint. That is after the replacement all the combination of the replaced smaller denomination and the replacing denominations should reproduce all the numbers previously expressed. My replacement of 19x5 with 3x25+2x10 (analyzing with by dividing through by their GCD 5) leaves odd but undivisble-by-5 multiples of 5 cents unreproducible from 3x25 and 2x10. So we need 1x5. So we are left with (3x25,4x10,1x5,4x1). So we still have to try out some cases. Do you agree?